# How can I set timezone in simple form datetime field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, simple-form, simple-form-for

I have a model with a datetime field, and is stored in UTC, how can I display that date in simple form gem in a specific timezone?

Already tried with the option `input_html: {value: @model.date.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)')}`

Note: I can't change the timezone of rails app

Comment: What's the result of your test? UTC still? What's the timezone for the rails app? What's the value of `@model.date` and `@model.date.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)')`

Comment: the form  sticks with UTC all the time, if a call `@model.date.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)')` e.g. in console or display in a view, it converts it

Comment: I had the opposite requirement in a project, show UTC and my solution was to create my own `UtcDateSelectInput`, this was for `Formtastic`, but a similar/analog solution should work with simple_form. The custom input inherits from DateSelectInput and override the value method as follows: `super.utc if super.respond_to? :utc`. I hope that helps.

Comment: I wonder if you pass string to `value` instead of `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` object (which is the result of `in_time_zone`). It will probably solve your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will work if you set the timezone in the controller:

Example:

```
around_action :set_time_zone, if: :current_user

private

def set_time_zone(&block)
   Time.use_zone(current_user.time_zone, &block)
end
```