# Simple form time uses incorrect zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, simple-form

I am using `simple_form` to set a time for start and end of the event. However, it shows time in wrong timezone.

My controller:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @event = Event.new(start_time: 1.hour.since(now), end_time: 2.hours.since(now))
    render 'edit'
  end
  ...
  private
  ...
  def now
    Time.zone.now
  end
end
```

My view (using slim):

```
= simple_form_for @event do |f|
  = f.input :name
  = f.input :start_time
  = f.input :end_time

  = f.input :camera_ids, collection: Camera.all, as: :check_boxes

  = f.button :submit, class:'btn-primary'
```

I live in `+03:00` zone. And the view renders both times 2 hours ago and 1 hour ago respectively. It is simply time in `UTC`, however, I want it in actual timezone. It saves in the database with the same timezone.

My console output for `Time.zone.now` or `Time.current` is right and uses `+03:00` timezone. How can I explain timezones for `simple_form`?

========

Upd

I tried to render time without `simple_form`. If I use
`= select_datetime @event.start_time.in_time_zone('Moscow')` it works.

But setting `.in_time_zone('Moscow')` for `simple_form` does not do the trick =( Or, may be I do it wrong.

I also have a guess that that can be about the way `simple_form` presents datetime. If I use the standard helper, it sets up values like `start_time[hours]` (etc) for each field. `simple_form`, on the other hand, sets values from `start_time(4i)` (and so on). Maybe the problem is somewhere there.

Answer (score 0):

Set your config to `:local` and declare your timezone and it will save time with your timezone (no now method needed then).

Add this to config/application.rb

```
confit.time_zone = "Moscow"
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

Moscow will get you the +3 offset that you need, but you can choose your location or one close to it from [this list](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html).

Make sure you clear out the old records just to be sure, then create a new one and it should be set up in your local time.

Here is the [relevant part of the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-active-record) for the local flag.

Comment: Nope, it is still UTC in my form. And prints in UTC

Comment: I just edited to explicitly declare a +3 timezone, let me know if that works, just make sure you clear out the old records and restart the server.

Comment: I've already had this set up. I've added upd to post. May be that will be helpful

Comment: Just re-reading, are you actually saving the result of the new form to the DB with a create action or just populating an edit template? And if you are saving, is it being saved correctly?

Comment: Yes, I save it with `create`, but the first problem is that the time in form is wrong. If I render this form at eg. 17:00, I expect start_time to have the value 18:00 and end_time 19:00. But it shows 15:00 and 16:00 respectively.

Comment: Is the actual saved data in the DB wrong as well, or is it purely to do with simpleform?

Comment: Only with simple form

Answer (score 0):

To get the current timezone of the machine where the code is running:

```
Time.now.localtime
```

To change timezone for all controller actions `EventsController`, you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40770376/5746504).

Comment: Still UTC in form

Comment: @Ngoral so you need to check your database timezone because it is an edit form.

Comment: I think calling Time.now.local or smth loki this from console did it. Also i set a configuration parameter as in previous answer and it did not help. I don't know what else i can do

Answer (score 0):

If you set correctly in your config/application.rb

```
config.time_zone = "Moscow"
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

it should work.
I tried your code with the snippets you provided in the first place and the inputs display the local time with any time_zones i tested (like "Moscow", "Melbourne" or "America/Los_Angeles")

I don't think the problem comes from simple_form because you inject the input data directly from the controller (from the `@event`).

Maybe try to debug your controller with some `puts` to see what time zone is returned...:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    start_time = 1.hour.since(now)
    end_time = 2.hours.since(now)
    puts start_time #<== ...here
    puts end_time   #<== and here
    @event = Event.new(start_time: start_time, end_time: end_time)
    render 'edit'
  end

  def now
    Time.zone.now
  end
end
```